# How to set a value from an output statement within a if clause

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, output

I've this code in my stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VerifyBasketIdToUse_DBO]
        @Basket_IDD INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (SELECT MAX(Basket_Id) FROM [Order]) = (SELECT MAX(Basket_Id) FROM [Order] WHERE Order_PayState=1)
        EXEC DBO.InsertBasket_DBO
        SET @Basket_IDD = @Basket_Id OUTPUT

    ELSE
        SET @Basket_IDD = (SELECT MAX(Basket_Id)FROM [Order])

SELECT @Basket_IDD
END
```

and this one for the SP with the output value

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBasket_DBO]
        @Basket_Id INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basket]([Basket_Amount])
    OUTPUT inserted.Basket_Id
    values (0)
END
```

but Sql Server notices that my @Basket_Id OUTPUT  from the second Stored Procedure isn't defined in the first Stored Procedure, I don't understand why ? could someone help me ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VerifyBasketIdToUse_DBO]
        @Basket_IDD INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT MAX(Basket_Id) FROM [Order]) = (SELECT MAX(Basket_Id) FROM [Order] WHERE Order_PayState=1)
        BEGIN
        EXEC @Basket_IDD = dbo.InsertBasket_DBO
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @Basket_IDD = (SELECT MAX(Basket_Id)FROM [Order])
        END
SELECT @Basket_IDD
END
```

Comment: Multiple issues here, for one Include your parameters as part of the `exec` not as a separate `set` - which incidentally is always executed since you have no `begin/end` block

Comment: Your second SP is not returning the basket_id it is outputting it as a result set, you need to use `scope_identity()` I suspect

Comment: I've just edit the code, could you give me your feedback ?

Comment: Use terminators CONSISTENTLY. However, your code should not lie. The name VerifyBasketIdToUse_DBO is both misleading and  far to general. "Verify" does not, to me at least, imply changing the state of the database. And what exactly do you "verify"?  Seems to me you are simply getting the "next basket" (not much better as a name but it's your system). Nor do I see any reason for 2 procedures here. Both are trivial - why do you use two? You might have a race condition as well. Search to understand that term.

Comment: I need those procedures to be used apart one from another, that's why even if they are trivial, I prefer to have 2 SP than 1

Answer (score 0):

Inside first procedure, instead of

```
EXEC DBO.InsertBasket_DBO
SET @Basket_IDD = @Basket_Id OUTPUT
```

use

```
EXEC DBO.InsertBasket_DBO @Basket_IDD OUTPUT
```

In second procedure, replace

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basket]([Basket_Amount])
OUTPUT inserted.Basket_Id
values (0)
```

with

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Basket]([Basket_Amount])
values (0)
select @Basket_Id = scope_identity()
```

I can't check syntax and results just now, but I hope this gives you some directions :)

Comment: why drop the output id parameter ?

Comment: I can't see any use of `output` clause (it is not parameter!) there - this generates just recordset, which usually is used to capture info into some temporary table or so, quite usable for statements, affecting multiple rows. It definitely does NOT give value to containing procedure ouptput parameters - those you have to assign in other ways (set, select).

Comment: ok thank you very much for you answer !